# Define a random variable with a list of numbers and their associated probabilities with Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, statistics

I am trying to resolve exercices from a statistic book with `Spark` to introduce myself step by step to `MLib`. But yet, it's only basic statistics tools.

A simple problem that comes is a random variable defined with this distribution of probabilties :

```
x   | 1    2    3    4    5    6
---------------------------------
Px  |0.1  0.4  0.2  0.1  0.1  0.1
```

I can calculate expected value and variance from it with a pen and a paper. But I would like to use `Spark` instead.
However, I see no way to declare a list of numbers accompanied by a list of probabilities to occur.

How can I do that with `Spark` ?
Is `MLib` already required for this simple calculation of expected value and variance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dataframe with two columns `x` and `Px` and then e.g. for the expected value do `df.agg(sum(col("x") * col("Px")).alias("expected_value")).first()`
For the variance you would need to use the variance formula.
MLib is not required for this

Answer (score 1):

@Paul (below, this post has been inserted before yours ? Strange)
It works. But it's a bit long.

```java
@Test
@DisplayName("E8.2 : Déterminer la distribution de probabilité d'une v.a. X")
public void distributionVariableAleatoireX() {
   StructType schema = new StructType()
     .add("x", IntegerType, false)
     .add("Px", DoubleType, false);

   List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<>();
   rows.add(RowFactory.create(1, 0.1));
   rows.add(RowFactory.create(2, 0.4));
   rows.add(RowFactory.create(3, 0.2));
   rows.add(RowFactory.create(4, 0.1));
   rows.add(RowFactory.create(5, 0.1));
   rows.add(RowFactory.create(6, 0.1));
   Dataset<Row> ds = this.session.createDataFrame(rows, schema);

   double esperance = ds.agg(sum(col("x").multiply(col("Px")))).first().getDouble(0);

   Column variation = col("x").minus(esperance);
   Column variationCarre = variation.multiply(variation);
   Column termeCalculVariance = col("Px").multiply(variationCarre);

   double variance = ds.agg(sum(termeCalculVariance)).first().getDouble(0);

   LOGGER.info("E(X) = {}, V(X) = {}", esperance, variance);
}
```

E(X) = 3.0
V(X) = 2.2